# Open CV java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: n_Mat randomly happening

Tags: android, opencv, mat

I've got an app on the market using openCV with something like 300.000 downloads. I often got a crash report (maybe 1 user out of 50) with this error (never got this bug myself on Wildfire, Nexus 4/One/S):

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: n_Mat at
>   org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method) at
>   org.opencv.core.Mat.(Mat.java:471) at
>   org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.initializeCamera(JavaCameraView.java:382)
>   at
>   org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.connectCamera(JavaCameraView.java:450)
>   at
>   org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.onEnterStartedState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:397)
>   at
>   org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.processEnterState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:355)
>   at
>   org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.checkCurrentState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:348)
>   at
>   org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.surfaceChanged(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:223)
>   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:558) at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1921)
>   at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1528) at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1264) at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I use static initialization for OpenCV (as I don't want my users to download other app when installing my app) and copied all the needed libs .so in `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `mips`, `x86`.

Also I know the crash happens when the activity starts and the most on this devices (don't know if this could be device related): ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 985N (one_touch_985N_gsm), Nexus One (passion), Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830D)...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same behavior when I tried to use the static library initialization.Static initialization is not to be used as mentioned in the [OpenCV introduction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).This is because the native libraries may not be loaded for OpenCV, before accessing the Java code if async initialization is not used. The reason for this happening is OpenCV just provides a wrapper to C++(in this case JNI code). Hence, this might happen "randomly" as the libraries may get loaded before app starts accessing the OpenCV part of code, which may result in no crash. Furthermore, the app actually would run the next time after the crash as the libraries might have been loaded in the last crash.

In summary, it is safer to use the async initialization for production code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as we want to keep our app as simple as possible is there any other way to do that without downloading the openCV app?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of the issues of using OpenCV with android.  I am not an android dev,but I think if you can find a way to initialize the native C++ libs before invoking the OpenCV part of code, or write your own wrapper for the C++ code (if it is only a small part of your code), it might work, although it would be laborious if you use many parts of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this is what I had fears about.. I'll dig into finding a secure way to load C++ code.